# Is there a way to sketch the background of the container in half on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I know that I can use a gradient, but both gradient options are not suitable for me, since I need to fill the background of the container as a progress bar. I can use the CustomPainter, but by design the container has a border radius and I don’t know how to make a border radius using the CustomPainter. Are there any ideas how to do this?

Comment: just one suggestion can this be achieved with  two container , one with full size widget and the second with varying width inside the first one , so the second container has the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to use a `Stack` widget

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Some Stuff"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 300.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are building the component you can access screen width and height using media query, divide it by any number you want and pass it as an argument to your Container for example.

```
Containter(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
)
```

If you want to make it dynamic, you can replace numbers with variables and redraw based on changes of this variable.